# My wallpaper and lockscreen turn grey/snowy after closing laptop and re-opening

Tags: desktop-background, 19.04

Just freshly installed 19.04 on my laptop (dell inspiron) and when I close it and re-open the wallpaper changes to a snowy/grey pciture.

snowy/grey background
[image: snowy/grey background]

I can change the background to a new picture, but when I go back to the original I still get this grey snow. Any ideas driver updates maybe?

Comment: Can you attach a picture so we get a better idea of what you are encountering?

Comment: There's a link to the picture where it says snowy/grey background. Sorry this is my first question here. Is there a better way to attach a picture?

Comment: That works I probably just missed it, my bad!

Comment: 1a. Do you have any gnome's extensions installed? 1b. Can you show us the image from `gnome-tweaks` ( `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks` -> open gnome tweaks -> `Extensions` tab )? 2. Have you encrypted your home folder? 3. Is your background somewhere outside your $HOME folder?

Comment: The same is happening to me. Could you solve the problem?

Comment: I had to re-install. This wasn't a big deal to me at the time because it was a fresh install. I know that doesn't help most though